# RestKit RKMappingResult gives [__NSCFBoolean length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, json, api, restkit

I am fetching data from the New York Times Bestsellers JSON API using Reskit. I believe I have an issue with my attributes mapping. A typical JSON object that has to be fetched looks like the structure below. My code is also shown. The API call does return objects as matching the number of expected results but the RKMappingResult in the requestDataFromAPI method returns "[__NSCFBoolean length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance". I am not able to access them as printing Books gives nil. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
{
    "status":"OK",
    "copyright":"Copyright (c) 2016 The New York Times Company.  All Rights Reserved.",
    "num_results":10,
    "last_modified":"2016-03-04T13:12:31-05:00",
    "results":
        {
         "list_name":"Animals",
         "bestsellers_date":"2016-02-27",
         "published_date":"2016-03-13",
         "display_name":"Animals",
         "normal_list_ends_at":10,
         "updated":"MONTHLY",
         "books": [
            {"rank":1,
            "rank_last_week":0,
            "weeks_on_list":0,
            "asterisk":0,
            "dagger":0,
            "primary_isbn10":"0802123414",
            "primary_isbn13":"9780802123411",
            "publisher":"Grove Atlantic",
            "description":"A grief-stricken British woman decides to raise a goshawk, a fierce bird that is notoriously difficult to tame.",
            "price":0,
            "title":"H IS FOR HAWK","author":"Helen Macdonald",
            "contributor":"by Helen Macdonald",

            "isbns": [
                {"isbn10":"0802123414",
                "isbn13":"9780802123411"
                },
                {"isbn10":"1448130727",
                "isbn13":"9781448130726"
                },
                {"isbn10":"1481530968",
                "isbn13":"9781481530965"
                },
                {"isbn10":"148153095X",
                "isbn13":"9781481530958"
                },
                {"isbn10":"1410483614",
                "isbn13":"9781410483614"
                },
                {"isbn10":"0802124739",
                "isbn13":"9780802124739"
                }]
        }
    }

    - (void) initializeRestAPI
    {
        // Initialize RestKit using API base address
        NSURL * baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.nytimes.com"];
        RKObjectManager * objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];

        // Initialize Core Data's managed object model from the bundle
        NSManagedObjectModel * managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

        // Initialize RestKit's managed object store
        RKManagedObjectStore * managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
        objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

        // Complete Core Data stack initialization via RestKit
        [managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
        NSString * persistentStorePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataModel.sqlite"];
        NSString * seedDatabasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"RKSeedDatabase" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        NSError * error;

        NSPersistentStore * persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:persistentStorePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:seedDatabasePath withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
        NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

        // Create RestKit's managed object contexts
        [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

        // Configure a managed object cache
        managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

        [self setupEntityMappingForObjectStore:managedObjectStore withObjectManager:objectManager];
        [self requestDataFromAPI];
    }

    -(void) setupEntityMappingForObjectStore: (RKManagedObjectStore *) managedObjectStore withObjectManager: (RKObjectManager *) objectManager
    {
        RKEntityMapping * bookListMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"BookList" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
        bookListMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"listName"];
        [bookListMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:
                        @{@"results.list_name": @"listName",
                        @"results.bestsellers_date": @"bestsellersDate",
                        @"results.published_date": @"publishedDate",
                        @"results.display_name": @"displayName",
                        @"results.normal_list_ends_at": @"normalListEndsAt",
                        @"results.updated": @"updated"
                        }];

        RKEntityMapping * bookMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
        bookMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"title"];
        [bookMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:
                    @{@"rank": @"rank",
                    @"rank_last_week": @"rankLastWeek",
                    @"weeks_on_list": @"weeksOnList",
                    @"primary_isbn10": @"primaryIsbn10",
                    @"primary_isbn13": @"primaryIsbn13",
                    @"amazon_product_url": @"productUrl",
                    @"book_image": @"bookImage",
                    @"publisher": @"publisher",
                    @"description": @"bookDescription",
                    @"title": @"title",
                    @"contributor": @"contributor",
                    @"author": @"author",
                    @"price": @"price"
                    }];

        [bookListMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"results.books" toKeyPath:@"books" withMapping:bookMapping]];

        RKResponseDescriptor * bookListResponseDescriptor =
        [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:bookListMapping
                                                 method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                            pathPattern:nil
                                                keyPath:@"results.books"
                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)
        ];

        [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:bookListResponseDescriptor];

        // Enable Activity Indicator Spinner
        [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;
    }

    - (void)fetchBooksFromContext
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext * context = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
        NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"BookList"];
        NSSortDescriptor * descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"listName" ascending:YES];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[descriptor];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        BookList * bookList = [fetchedObjects firstObject];
        NSArray * books = [bookList.books allObjects];
        //NSArray * books = [fetchedObjects firstObject];
        NSLog(@"Books: %@",books);
    }

    - (void)requestDataFromAPI
    {
        NSDictionary * apiKeyData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"apiKeyData"];
        NSString * apiKey = [apiKeyData objectForKey:@"apiKeyData"];
        NSLog(@"requestDataFromAPI apiKey: %@",apiKey);
        NSString * requestPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"/svc/books/v3/lists/%@?&api-key=%@",_categoryListName, apiKey];

        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager]
                getObjectsAtPath:requestPath
                  parameters:nil
                     success: ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
                                {
                                [self fetchBooksFromContext];
                                }
                      failure: ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
                                {
                                RKLogError(@"Loading from API failed with error: %@", error);
                                }
         ];
    }
```

The core data object models are as shown

```
#import "BookList.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface BookList (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *listName;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSDate *bestsellersDate;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSDate *publishedDate;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *displayName;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *normalListEndsAt;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *updated;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<Book *> *books;

@end

@interface BookList (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addBooksObject:(Book *)value;
- (void)removeBooksObject:(Book *)value;
- (void)addBooks:(NSSet<Book *> *)values;
- (void)removeBooks:(NSSet<Book *> *)values;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

#import "Book.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Book (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *rankLastWeek;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *weeksOnList;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *primaryIsbn10;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *primaryIsbn13;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *productUrl;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *bookImageUrl;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *publisher;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *bookDescription;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *contributor;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *author;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *price;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Comment: somewhere you're treating an `NSNumber` which wraps a `BOOL` as an `NSString` - which line is it that crashes? where in your data model do you have this attribute? should it be a number or a string?

Comment: @Wain I made a fix for weeks_on_list which was a string instead of a number. However, printing the result mapping still gives the boolean error. I can't see which other attribute I could be treating as string instead of NSNumber. See the edit in my post. The crash when executing the fetch request gives the error: **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath title not found in entity <NSSQLEntity BookList id=2>**

Comment: Indeed, book list doesn't have a title attribute

Comment: @Wain thanks for picking that up. I have fixed it. That is just for fetching the results from Core Data using the sortdescriptor as key. However, even with the right descriptor, nothing is fetched. Books is null. The web request fives **(200 OK / 10 objects) [request=0.4736s mapping=0.0105s total=0.5383s]** which is showing 10 objects are returned, yet they don't seem to write to the database.

Comment: Turn on trace logging, print the mapping result, what does it show

Comment: @Wain printing the mapping result prints out **-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e52a60
0x16d60310** See the additional code I have added for the core data object models. Perhaps you could see where I have the wrong data type causing the NSCGNumber length error, otherwise I can't seem to find it.

Comment: have you overridden `description` somewhere, or added a property with that name?

Comment: @Wain **I have solved it!** I had set up the project without selecting core data because I knew I would not be using the boiler code generated in AppDelegate as RestKit would do it. It appears that it wasn't linking up the .xcdatamodel correctly when I included it manually. Also, because I had left the entities as optional, it was not showing that data is not written to it. Thank you for your questions, they helped to diagnose.